# Installing R package "WRS"

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install the package "WRS" in R Studio Version 1.2.5033 but it does not work. I could not find answers for the problem online, thus I am starting possible ones here.

The code looks like this:

install.packages("WRS", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

library(WRS)

or

source("http://www-rcf.usc.edu/~rwilcox/Rallfun-v14")

The website http://www-rcf.usc.edu/~rwilcox/Rallfun-v14 does not work anymore but it should work with the active website http://R-Forge.R-project.org.

Does anyone know what/where the problem may be? 
Furthermore, how can I install the package WRS in R Studio Version 1.2.5033? 
At last, I know that the R Studio Version 1.2.5033 is one of the latest versions and maybe this is the problem. Yet, how can I solve it and keep using the version that I currently have?

Thanks!

Comment: Any output? Error messages? How do you know it isn't working?

Answer (score 5):

As others noted, post your error messages, and it's easier to help you.  For example, I tried to install and received the following error message:

```
ERROR: dependency 'akima' is not available for package 'WRS'
* removing 'C:/R/R-3.5.3/library/WRS'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘WRS’ had non-zero exit status
```

Note that it is requiring the library 'akima' to be installed, and seems to be having trouble doing that.  In this case, if you do the following, the installation "works":

```
install.packages('akima')   # install the problem dependency yourself
install.packages('WRS', repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

I put "works" in quotes because there are quite a few "possible error..." notes, so I don't know if all the functions work properly.  However, this does get you able to install the library.  Load the package with `library(WRS)` and the methods appear to be there for me.

Comment: Hy, thanks! I tried installing the "akima" package but it also did not work out. The error is: "ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘akima’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/akima’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘akima’ had non-zero exit status". I assume that the error related to the WRS package is indeed related to the absence of the package akima. Yet, I do not understand why akima is also not working. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I think if you get that working you will fix your issue.  At this point, I would ask what kind of OS are you using?  I am using Windows OS.  For MacOS, you may need xcode ([as referenced by a similar error message here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-compilation-failed-for-package-rlang/26886)).  For Linux, it depends... I suggest searching around that error message for other packages.